# Size content vertically to viewport

Tags: html, css, viewport, image-resizing

I am creating a page to show enlarged views of a photographs. I want the page show a header at the top, a footer at the bottom, and the image of the photograph filling in all of the space between the the header and the footer. The photographs have varying sizes and may have landscape or portrait orientation. I have no difficulty sizing the width to the viewport. I have no problem doing this if the page only contains the image and nothing else. Despite searching, reading, and trial and error I cannot discern how to size the content vertically to meet this guideline. For example:

```
<header>
    <h1>Some header stuff</h1>
    <p>Such as a navigation bar at the top of the viewport.</p>
</header>
<main>
    <h1>Image</h1>
    <p>An image that should fill up the space in between</p>
    xxxxxxxxxxxxx<br />
    xxxxxxxxxxxxx<br />
    xxxxxxxxxxxxx<br />
    xxxxxxxxxxxxx<br />
    xxxxxxxxxxxxx<br />
</main>
<footer>
    <h1>Some footer stuff</h1>
    <p>Such as a logo, link to privacy page etc.</p>
</footer>
```

Perhaps this is not possible. Any ideas?

Comment: Since you are fixing both the width and the height, I suppose you will want to use a strategy similar to `background-size: cover`, so that the aspect ratio of the image is preserved?

Comment: Where is your CSS? Please read [how to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Yes, I want to preserve the aspect ratio. I would also like to preserve the content as an img  or figure element with an img to that I can have things such as the alt attribute.

Comment: I do not have CSS that does this. I am looking for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The layout is actually totally possible, but requires some slight modification to your HTML. You will want to wrap your `<header>`, `<main>` and `<footer>` element in a wrapper div, which is set to `display: flex; flex-direction: column`, so that they will use CSS flexbox to perform space-filling layout requirements.

Then, in the `<main>` element, you do the same CSS flexbox trick. However, you should wrap your `<img>` element with a `<div>`, which is set to grow to whatever space that is available.

So far, your layout will look like this:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <header><!-- Header content --></header>
  <main>
    <!-- More content -->
    <div class="image">
      <img src="..." />
    </div>
  </main>
  <footer><!-- Footer content --></footer>
</div>
```

Your `<img>` element is then set to position itself absolutely, covering its parent `<div>` completely, and taking advantage of [`object-fit: cover`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit) to size itself to fill all space while preserving aspect ratio.

Here is a proof-of-concept example. However, you might want to view it on full page (or check this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/z2x83dby/)), since the code snippet inline preview is too small to demonstrate the layout:

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}

header, footer {
  background-color: steelblue;
  color: #eee;
}

main {
  flex: 1 1 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}

.image {
  flex: 1 1 100%;
  position: relative;
}

img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <header>
      <h1>Some header stuff</h1>
      <p>Such as a navigation bar at the top of the viewport.</p>
  </header>
  <main>
      <h1>Image</h1>
      <p>An image that should fill up the space in between</p>
      <div class="image">
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1586109803336-c02797ffdcc0?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=634&q=80" />
      </div>
  </main>
  <footer>
      <h1>Some footer stuff</h1>
      <p>Such as a logo, link to privacy page etc.</p>
  </footer>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Terry.

Comment: I found that Terry's proof of concept did not preserve the aspect ratio of the image. That was easily fixed by changing the img element's width attribute from 100% to auto.

Comment: If you use `object-fit: cover` the aspect ratio should be preserved. If you change it to width or height auto it will only work for a combination of viewport aspect ratio + image aspect ratio.

Answer (score 0):

```css
header{
height:10vh;
}
footer{
height:10vh;
}
main{
height:65vh;
background:url("https://www.bing.com/th?id=ABT63B35E950543A69BB040AEFA5BFCA186A43A5798E5E9B96844F4CE0ED7176910&w=608&h=200&c=2&rs=1&pid=SANGAM") no-repeat center center fixed;
background-size:cover;
}
```

```html
<header>
    <h1>Some header stuff</h1>
    <p>Such as a navigation bar at the top of the viewport.</p>
</header>
<main>
    
</main>
<footer>
    <h1>Some footer stuff</h1>
    <p>Such as a logo, link to privacy page etc.</p>
</footer>
```

Comment: I have tried approaches similar to that but when I run your example and shrink the browser window vertically, the header bottom overlaps the image and the footer bottom get clipped. I believe I need to find a way to scale the size of the header and footer content to changes in the viewport size.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution incorporating Terry's Ideas:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <style>
    * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    
    html,
    body {
      height: 100%;
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
    }
    
    header,
    footer {
      background-color: steelblue;
      color: #eee;
      padding-left: 2rem;
    }
    
    main {
      flex: 1 1 100%;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      height: 100%;
      padding-left: 2rem;
    }
    
    .body-wrapper {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      height: 100%;
    }
    
    .image-wrapper {
      flex: 1 1 100%;
      position: relative;
    }
    
    img {
      display: block;
      max-width: 100%;
      max-height: 100%;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      right: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
      object-fit: cover;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="body-wrapper">
    <header>
      <h1>Navigation Bar Goes Here</h1>
    </header>
    <main>
      <h1>Photo Caption Goes Here</h1>
      <div class="image-wrapper">
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1586109803336-c02797ffdcc0?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=634&q=80" alt="Photo: Copy of Photo Captions Goes Here" />
      </div>
      <h2>The Album Caption Goes here</h2>
    </main>
    <footer>
      <h1>Footer Goes Here</h1>
    </footer>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```